Template Rendering in Dynamic Task Mapping
I am trying to run a batch on dataproc, and I am submitting the DAG run timestamp as an environment variable in the spark properties spark.dataproc.driverEnv.REPORTING_TIMESTAMP.
# spark properties for dataproc job submission
spark_properties = (
    "spark.app.name=levi-spark-pp-promo-reporting,"
    "spark.dynamicallocation.enabled=true,"
    "spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=8,"
    "spark.executor.instances=8,"
    "spark.driver.cores=4,"
    "spark.driver.memory=16g,"
    "spark.executor.cores=4,"
    "spark.executor.memory=16g,"
    "spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2,"
    f"spark.dataproc.driverEnv.ENV={env},"
    "spark.dataproc.driverEnv.REPORTING_TIMESTAMP={{ ts_nodash[:8] }}-{{ ts_nodash[9:11] }}:{{ ts_nodash[11:13] }}:{{ ts_nodash[13:] }},"
)

Instead of rendering the template the code reads REPORTING_TIMESTAMP as string like this {{ ts_nodash[:8] }}-{{ ts_nodash[9:11] }}:{{ ts_nodash[11:13] }}:{{ ts_nodash[13:] }}.
    ##### Run Adapters #####
    @task(trigger_rule="all_done")
    def generate_adapters(**context):
        param_dicts = []
        branch = context["params"]["branch"]
        build_number = context["params"]["build_number"]
        dataproc_image_tag = context["params"]["dataproc_image_tag"]
        countries_to_include = context["params"]["countries_to_include"]
        countries_to_exclude = context["params"]["countries_to_exclude"]
        campaigns_to_include = context["params"]["campaigns_to_include"]
        
        for adapter_func in adapters_to_run:
            param_dict = {
                "name": f"mx_{adapter_func}_adapter_batch",
                "cmds": [
                    "gcloud",
                    "dataproc",
                    "batches",
                    "submit",
                    "pyspark",
                    os.path.join(
                        "gs://",
                        deps_bucket,
                        dependency_path,
                        branch,
                        build_number,
                        "apply_adapters.py",
                    ),
                    f"--project={gcp_project}",
                    f"--region={region}",
                    f"--deps-bucket={deps_bucket}",
                    f"--service-account={service_account}",
                    f"--subnet={subnetwork_uri}",
                    f"--container-image={dataproc_image}:{dataproc_image_tag}",
                    f"--version={dataproc_version}",
                    "--py-files",
                    os.path.join(
                        "gs://",
                        deps_bucket,
                        dependency_path,
                        branch,
                        build_number,
                        "src.zip",
                    ),
                    "--files",
                    os.path.join(
                        "gs://",
                        deps_bucket,
                        dependency_path,
                        branch,
                        build_number,
                        "settings.toml",
                    ),
                    f"--properties={spark_properties}",
                    f"--labels={spark_labels}",
                    f"--batch=mx-{adapter_func.replace('_', '-')}-adapter-batch-{file_date}",
                    "--",
                    f"--adapters_to_apply={adapter_func}",
                    f"--countries_to_include={countries_to_include}",
                    f"--countries_to_exclude={countries_to_exclude}",
                    f"--campaigns_to_include={campaigns_to_include}",
                ],
            }
            param_dicts.append(param_dict)
        return param_dicts

    generate_adapter_tasks = generate_adapters()

    run_adapters = KubernetesPodOperator.partial(
        image=f"google/cloud-sdk:latest",
        labels=labels,
        task_id="run_adapters",
        do_xcom_push=False,
        namespace="airflow-price-promo",
        service_account_name="airflow-worker",
        get_logs=True,
    ).expand_kwargs(generate_adapter_tasks)

How can I render this as a template and pass the timestamp?

EDIT: synced separately with OP and it is a bug in older Airflow versions when using templates in .expand_kwargs(). The first version that fixed the issue is Airflow 2.7.1, see this PR.
May I ask what versions you are using of both Airflow and the Kubernetes provider? Because I haven't been able to reproduce the issue.
I tried to run similar code using this mock-DAG:
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.pod import KubernetesPodOperator
import os

env = "dev"
gcp_project = "test"
region = "test"
deps_bucket = "test"
service_account = "test"
subnetwork_uri = "test"
dataproc_image = "test"
dataproc_version = "test"
dependency_path = "test"
labels = {"app": "test"}
file_date = "test"
spark_labels = "test"


spark_properties = (
    "spark.app.name=levi-spark-pp-promo-reporting,"
    "spark.dynamicallocation.enabled=true,"
    "spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=8,"
    "spark.executor.instances=8,"
    "spark.driver.cores=4,"
    "spark.driver.memory=16g,"
    "spark.executor.cores=4,"
    "spark.executor.memory=16g,"
    "spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2,"
    f"spark.dataproc.driverEnv.ENV={env},"
    "spark.dataproc.driverEnv.REPORTING_TIMESTAMP={{ ts_nodash[:8] }}-{{ ts_nodash[9:11] }}:{{ ts_nodash[11:13] }}:{{ ts_nodash[13:] }},"
)


@dag(start_date=None, schedule=None, catchup=False, params={"campaigns_to_include": "f"})
def test2():

    ##### Run Adapters #####
    @task(trigger_rule="all_done")
    def generate_adapters(**context):
        param_dicts = []
        branch = "a"
        build_number = "b"
        dataproc_image_tag = "c"
        countries_to_include = "d"
        countries_to_exclude = "e"
        campaigns_to_include = context["params"]["campaigns_to_include"]
        
        for adapter_func in ["adapter1", "adapter2", "adapter3"]:
            param_dict = {
                "name": f"mx_{adapter_func}_adapter_batch",
                "cmds": [
                    "gcloud",
                    "dataproc",
                    "batches",
                    "submit",
                    "pyspark",
                    os.path.join(
                        "gs://",
                        branch,
                        build_number,
                        "apply_adapters.py",
                    ),
                    f"--project={gcp_project}",
                    f"--region={region}",
                    f"--deps-bucket={deps_bucket}",
                    f"--service-account={service_account}",
                    f"--subnet={subnetwork_uri}",
                    f"--container-image={dataproc_image}:{dataproc_image_tag}",
                    f"--version={dataproc_version}",
                    "--py-files",
                    os.path.join(
                        "gs://",
                        deps_bucket,
                        dependency_path,
                        branch,
                        build_number,
                        "src.zip",
                    ),
                    "--files",
                    os.path.join(
                        "gs://",
                        deps_bucket,
                        dependency_path,
                        branch,
                        build_number,
                        "settings.toml",
                    ),
                    f"--properties={spark_properties}",
                    f"--labels={spark_labels}",
                    f"--batch=mx-{adapter_func.replace('_', '-')}-adapter-batch-{file_date}",
                    "--",
                    f"--adapters_to_apply={adapter_func}",
                    f"--countries_to_include={countries_to_include}",
                    f"--countries_to_exclude={countries_to_exclude}",
                    f"--campaigns_to_include={campaigns_to_include}",
                ],
            }
            param_dicts.append(param_dict)
        return param_dicts

    generate_adapter_tasks = generate_adapters()

    run_adapters = KubernetesPodOperator.partial(
        image=f"google/cloud-sdk:latest",
        labels=labels,
        task_id="run_adapters",
        do_xcom_push=False,
        namespace="airflow-price-promo",
        service_account_name="airflow-worker",
        get_logs=True,
    ).expand_kwargs(generate_adapter_tasks)


test2()

with Airflow 2.10.2 (Astro CLI 12.1.1) and apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes 8.4.1.
and while of course I can't get the exact task to run without your setup, I get the timestamp rendered correctly in the rendered template:

